# Convert array with hex datatype to readable format using truffle console

Tags: truffle, ethereumjs

I am new to ethereum. I am using truffle to develop, deploy and interact with my solidity contract.I have a function in my contract which is as follows:

```
  function getResult(bytes32 name) public view returns (bytes32, bytes32,uint) {
        return (name,nameArray[name].pName,pCount[name]);
    }
```

Using truffle console I accessed it as follows:

```
var result = poe.getResult('QWERTY');
```

**poe: is the contract instance

the output of the function is:

```
[ '0x5157455254590000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  '0x456c656331000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
  BigNumber { s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 1 ] } ]
```

Can anyone help me in converting the output to a readable format(hex to string and bignumber to integer)

Any leads would be appreciated.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

You convert the BigNumber by just calling `.toNumber()` on it, and you can convert the hex string using [web3's built-in `web3.toAscii()` function](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii).  Bonus points, web3's function automatically handles the leading `0x` so you don't have to!

Edit: Note that this function returns three values, `(name,nameArray[name].pName,pCount[name])`, which is why you're getting an array.  A full conversion would look like

```
convertedResult = [web3.toAscii(result[0]), web3.toAscii(result[1]), result[2].toNumber()]
```

Answer (score 2):

the output is in array format. is there a way to extract the individual elements. I tried using toNumber and web3.toAscii() but doesn't seem to work

Comment: I tried using your method on similar function, but it returns undefined. var test = contractInstanceName.getList(). var convertedRes = web3.toAscii(test) :returns undefined